# RuntimeError: Invalid Form Body: code 50035

Tags: discord, autocode

I am using autocode API references for testing purposes.

I am trying to create a channel with permissions but I got an error :

[image]

This is just for the example. I've also tried with real parameters like

```
{
        id: XXXXXXX,
        type: 0,
        deny: `${1 << 10}`
}
```

but I get the same error. I cannot enter the value as an object. It automatically converts in string.

Any suggestion ?